# Return php array using ajax

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax

I am trying to fill a html table with an array. The function is in php and when I call it, without ajax, but just with php it works fine but as soon as I try calling it using ajax, it returns an empty array

```
        function getAJAX(){
        var token = window.token;
        $.ajax({ url: 'functions.php',
                 data: {action: 'openSales', access: token}
                 type: 'post',
                 success: function(output) {
                              document.getElementById('OpenSales').innerHTML = '';
                             var output = jQuery.parseJSON(output);
                              makeTable($('#OpenSales'),output,'overdueSales');
                          }
        }); 
    }
```

The makeTable function does work when called outside the ajax function so that is not the problem, the php code is

```
        if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        $token = $_POST['access'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'openSales' : echo json_encode(getOverdueSales($token)); break;
            case 'blah' : blah();break;
        }
    }
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Where does `$token` come from?

Comment: where is $token defined?

Comment: it all works fine if i set the return to something such as echo 'Hello World'; instead of echo json_encode(getOverdueSales($token)), so the problem is that it doesn't return the array correctly.. Returns it empty instead of a full array.

Comment: $token is the accessToken, if i call getOverdueSales($token) it does return the php array. Just want to be able to do it through ajax rather then straight through a php call     Though just realized I didn't pass it through the ajax call so I will add that and see if that works

Comment: I updated the code to include the $token variable